# Magento 2.1, manuall install extensions wont work

Tags: php, magento, mailchimp

For the last couple of days I cannot install any extension on live server. The problems that I am having:

1. Web setup wizard is not showing. Found a workaround to access it via /admin/backend/setup ... only to say Upgrad already in progress and it is like that forever, no clue what is going on.
2. Tried to install it manually following the tutorials on web.

   - Step 1: Download/purchase the extension
   - Step 2: Unzip the file in a temporary directory
   - Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory
   - Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management
   - Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:

php ­f bin/magento setup:upgrade

So I did it.

- I unzipped the file and get ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey-3.0.7 folder.
- I copy that folder in my public_html/magento/ folder (magento root folder). So now i got ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey-3.0.7 inside my root magento.
- php ­f bin/magento setup:upgrade, also tried static content deploy, and nothing.

I can install this extension via composer on my localhost, but I can't manually. On my live server I need to install it manually.

I am guessing that all tutorials on the web are missing some steps. Do I need to follow some naming convention. Some say that I should copy that folder in pub/code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the contents of the `ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey-3.0.7` folder to `app/code/Ebizmarts/MageMonkey`
if `app/code/Ebizmarts/MageMonkey` does not exist, create those folders first.
Your directory structure should look like this:

[image: Ebizmarts_MageMonkey for Magento 2directory structure]